# Custom query filter not working on woocommerce category page

Tags: query, woocommerce-offtopic, pre-get-posts

I am trying to make custom filter for my woocommerce website.
Everything is working fine in the shop page, but when I go to the archive page the filters are not working. I am recording each filter property in the URL address.

The code in the shop page is working, but in the archive page ( category ) its not working. Does anybody know how to manipulate the SQL query in the archive page ? My current code is:

```
function modify_query($query) {
    if(!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'product') {
        if(isset($_GET["fillter"])) {
            $arr[] = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'pc_filters',
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => $_GET["fillter"],
            );
            $query->set('tax_query', array(
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                            array($arr)
                        )
                    );          
            return $query;
        }
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'modify_query');
```

But its working only in the shop page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure at first glance why this is only working on your home page and not your archive pages, but there are a few things wrong with the way this function is written. So, I've rewritten it for you below - using this instead *might* solve the problem if it was introducing an esoteric bug before.

A couple of things to note:

- `relation` should not be used with `tax_query` when there is only one inner query ([reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters))
- your `tax_query` was three arrays deep - it should only be two
- as `pre_get_posts` is an action, there is no return value accepted (in this case, `$query` is [passed by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php), so it doesn't need returning)
- `"filter"` was misspelled as `"fillter"` (while this wouldn't have broken the code on its own, it *could* have mixed you up during testing if you used `?filter=` in your query string)
- I've also added sanitisation of the querystring variable you're bringing in, by way of [absint()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/absint/) given it is a `term_id`

With that said, here's the simplified function:

```
function modify_query($query) {
  if( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'product') {
    if( isset( $_GET['filter'] ) ) {

      $query->set( 'tax_query', array (
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'pc_filters',
          'field'    => 'term_id',
          'terms'    => absint( $_GET['filter'] ),
        )
      ));

    }
  }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'modify_query' );
```

I haven't tested this, but it should do what you were intending in a slightly simpler way, which might solve your problem.

If this doesn't solve it, it might be due to the query that WooCommerce is using on the archive pages, in particular, the value of `query_vars['post_type']`. WooCommerce specifics are off-topic here and I'm not actually familiar with it myself, but as far as general WordPress goes, you could use `print_r($query->query_vars);` within the above function to see what you have to work with, and then modify accordingly. Alternatively, you could remove the `post_type` check altogether, although then this code would also apply to your general posts and pages which might not be what you're after.